# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1['

Tags: vb.net, list, class

The error I get at Runtime is

```
Unable to cast object of type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TCPClientClean.ChatClient+LogTime]'
to type
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TCPClientClean.TimeLogLabel+LogTime]'.
```

I have a class that is used for logging an event and saving the time stamp.  I then want to save the list that is made in the `TimeLogLabel` class and then reload at start up. The saving to a text file is solved and works but I am not understanding how to get the saved list back into the `TimeLogLabel` class.

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Public Class TimeLogLabel
Inherits Label

Private m_VaraibleToSet As Boolean
<System.ComponentModel.Category("Control")> _
Public Property VaraibleToSet() As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_VaraibleToSet
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        m_VaraibleToSet = value
    End Set
End Property
Private m_PrefixText As String = "Prefix Text"
<System.ComponentModel.Category("Control")> _
Public Property PrefixText() As String
    Get
        Return m_PrefixText
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_PrefixText = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Class LogTime
    Private m_EventName As String
    Public Property EventName() As String
        Get
            Return m_EventName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_EventName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StartT As String
    Public Property StartT() As String
        Get
            Return m_StartT
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_StartT = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StopT As String
    Public Property StopT() As String
        Get
            Return m_StopT
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_StopT = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_TSpan As String
    Public Property TSpan() As String
        Get
            Return m_TSpan
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_TSpan = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New( _
  ByVal m_EventName As String, _
  ByVal m_StartT As String, _
  ByVal m_StopT As String, _
  ByVal m_TSpan As String)
        EventName = m_EventName
        StartT = m_StartT
        StopT = m_StopT
        TSpan = m_TSpan
    End Sub
End Class


Public TimeList As List(Of LogTime) = New List(Of LogTime)

    Public Sub StartTimer()
    If Ons = False Then
        Ons = True
        EventIdInt = EventIdInt + 1
        EventIdStg = ""
        If EventIdInt <= 9 Then
            EventIdStg = "0" & CStr(EventIdInt)
        ElseIf EventIdInt >= 9 Then
            EventIdStg = CStr(EventIdInt)
        End If
        StartTime = Now
        TimeList.Add(New LogTime(PrefixText & " " & EventIdStg,     "StartTime " & StartTime, "", ""))
        Timer.Enabled = True
        Timer.Start()
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub StopTimer()
    If Ons = True Then
        Ons = False
        EventIdInt = EventIdInt + 1
        EventIdStg = ""
        If EventIdInt <= 9 Then
            EventIdStg = "0" & CStr(EventIdInt)
        ElseIf EventIdInt >= 9 Then
            EventIdStg = CStr(EventIdInt)
        End If
        StopTime = Now
        TimeList.Add(New LogTime(PrefixText & " " & EventIdStg, "", _           "Stop Time " & StopTime, " Up Time " & AccTimeStg))
        Timer.Enabled = False
        Timer.Stop()
    End If
End Sub






Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq  
Public Class ChatClient   ' Form that has "TimeLogLabel" on the form


Public Class LogTime
    Private m_EventName As String
    Public Property EventName() As String
        Get
            Return m_EventName
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_EventName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StartT As String
    Public Property StartT() As String
        Get
            Return m_StartT
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_StartT = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_StopT As String
    Public Property StopT() As String
        Get
            Return m_StopT
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_StopT = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_TSpan As String
    Public Property TSpan() As String
        Get
            Return m_TSpan
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_TSpan = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New( _
  ByVal m_EventName As String, _
  ByVal m_StartT As String, _
  ByVal m_StopT As String, _
  ByVal m_TSpan As String)
        EventName = m_EventName
        StartT = m_StartT
        StopT = m_StopT
        TSpan = m_TSpan
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub ChatClient_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e s    System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim TimeListSaved As List(Of LogTime) = New List(Of LogTime)
    ' Dim TimeListSaved As IEnumerable(Of LogTime) = New List(Of LogTime)

    Dim Sartuptime As DateTime = Now
    TimeListSaved.Add(New LogTime("Prefix&EvebtId 01", "Start Time " & UpStartTime, "Stop Time", "Up Time"))

LAtSvrComm.TimeList.AddRange(TimeListSaved)
' this is where I get my error
    ' Unable to cast object of type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TCPClientClean.ChatClient+LogTime]'
    'to type 
    'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TCPClientClean.TimeLogLabel+LogTime]'.
    End Sub

Private Sub ChatClient_FormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 

System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing


Dim FILE_NAME As String = "C:\LogSave.txt"
    Dim objWriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME)

    For Each TimeLogLabel In LAtSvrComm.TimeList
        objWriter.WriteLine(TimeLogLabel.EventName & " * " &     TimeLogLabel.StartT & " * " & TimeLogLabel.StopT & _
                            " * " & TimeLogLabel.TSpan)
    Next TimeLogLabel
    objWriter.WriteLine("end of " & LAtSvrComm.PrefixText)
    End Sub



    objWriter.Close()
end sub
```

Comment: Too much code. Shorten it down please.

Answer (score 0):

You declare 2 classes named `LogTime`, not 1. They're member classes, and they aren't automatically convertible between each other, so the CLR doesn't know how to convert for you (throwing this error).

That is, `TCPClientClean.ChatClient+LogTime` and `TCPClientClean.TimeLogLabel+LogTime` are **not** the same type.

Since it looks like you intend there to be only one `LogTime` class, declare that as a separate class (rather than as a class that is a member of another class) and remove the 2 different `LogTime`s you have now.

Comment: I think I understand what you mean but have a question.  The TimeLogLabel is a class in the project not in the form that is a member of another class.  So what I think you are saying is  to add a class to the project and then load my List and then add that list to the TimeLogLabel.addrange.  The reason I had not done that or thought of that is I don;t understand why I just can't add to the TimeLogLabel.LogTime class?  Is that because it is not accesible to add to from the Form? I will give the new separate class.

Comment: OK I added a new class LoadTimeLog that is the same as the other list classes.  I then load the event name, starttime, .ect and then '  
            LAtSvrComm.TimeList.AddRange(SvrTimeListSaved)' I get this error now  _Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TCPClientClean.LoadTimeLog]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TCPClientClean.TimeLogLabel+LogTime]'._

Answer (score 0):

this solved it.
on form load I will read the text file and then put the strings into the correct item.

```
      LAtSvrComm.TimeList.Add(New TimeLogLabel.LogTime("Prefix&EvebtId 01", "Start Time " & UpStartTime, "Stop Time", "Up Time"))
```

@Billy N thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  By explaining it the way you did made me come up with this solution.